# Catching session state events outside of global.asax (C#, .Net)?

Tags: c#, .net, session, events, state

I need to catch session state events using Session_Start() and Session_End(). The nature of my project restricts changing the source code so I cannot add these methods into the global.asax file. How would I do this? I have already tried inheriting the global.asax.cs class and added the methods there, but they do not hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with an [HTTP Module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx). Here's an example:

```
public class SessionCatchingModule : IHttpModule //You will need to import System.Web
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        //Get the SessionstateModule and attach our own events to it
        var module = context.Modules["Session"] as SessionStateModule;
        if (module != null)
        {
            module.Start += this.Session_Start;
            module.End += this.Session_end;
        }
    }

    private void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        //Oh look, a session has started
    }

    private void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        //Oh look, a session has ended
    }

}
```

Now in your `web.config` make sure the module is being loaded:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="SessionCatchingModule" 
         type="YourNamespace.Goes.Here., SessionCatchingModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```